# Zoomed, cropped icon in notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm creating a notification using NotificationCompat.Builder.  To set the large icon part of it, I'm using this:

```
bob = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
 .setLargeIcon(bm)
 .setAutoCancel(true)
 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher256)
 .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
 .setContentText(message)
 .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

The smallicon is displaying fine, but on some devices the large icon is zoomed in, and therefore cropped.  On other devices (handily, all the ones I can test it on) it works perfectly.

I'm not aware of any restrictions on what size this icon must be.  It's coming out of the users contacts list, so I can't control what goes in there, although I suppose I could resize/reformat it if that were the problem.

I'll continue to debug this (focussing on the logic which obtains the bitmap) but thought I'd ask in case I've overlooked something (non) obvious.    Perhaps it's possible for people to set contact photos on their devices which aren't suitable for notifications without some pre-processing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not really documented. :(

You can see from the [base template layout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/HEAD/core/res/res/layout/notification_template_base.xml) that the icon is just dunked in an `ImageView` with `android:scaleType="center"`, so anything bigger than the box (`@dimen/notification_large_icon_width`x`@dimen/notification_large_icon_height`) will just get cropped as it overflows its bounds.

The answer, then, as you can see from [dimens.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/HEAD/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml), is 64x64dp. You'll want to scale your Bitmaps accordingly before posting the notification.

Comment: Thanks. (Actually, I used 128x128 as 64x64 is too small.)

Comment: Don't forget your density conversions! It's 64 square dips, which is 128x128 _pixels_ on an xhdpi (2x) display.